# Largest $k$ such that $k \operatorname{Tr} H^2 C \le (\operatorname{Tr} H C)^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, inequality, convex-optimization, trace, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Suppose we are given $H$, a positive semidefinite $d\times d$matrix. How do I find $k$, the largest $k'$ such that the following holds for all positive semidefinite $C$ with unit trace?

$$k' \operatorname{Tr} H^2 C \le (\operatorname{Tr} H C)^2$$

Earlier [discussion](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4639576/998) shows that $k\ge\frac{\lambda_\text{min}(H)^2}{\lambda_\text{max}(H)^2}$. For the example below, this gives $k
\ge 0.01$ where true value is $k\approx 0.330579$. Is there a better bound with a nice closed-form expression?

We can use numerical optimization to find $k$ for specific $H$ like [this](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/Published/forum-Rbound.nb). For example, suppose

$$\text{H=}\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 10 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Then $$k = \frac{40}{121}$$

Realized by the following $C^*$

$$C^*=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 \frac{39}{176} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{7}{16} & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{4} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{11} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

[Notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/nn-linear/forum-Rbound.nb)

Motivation: $k\times d$ gives "critical batch-size" of minibatch SGD for solving linear least-squares problem with Hessian $H$ and optimal error distribution $C=C^*$. Critical batch-size for isotropic error distribution $C=I$ is analyzed [here](https://machine-learning-etc.ghost.io/batch-size-step-size-and-dimensionality-for-linear-least-squares/).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I played around a bit with your nice Mathematica code and it turns out that, indeed, if $H\neq 0$ the constant you are looking for does have a nice analytic expression:
$$
\boxed{k'=\frac{4\lambda_{\rm min}(H)\lambda_{\rm max}(H)}{(\lambda_{\rm min}(H)+\lambda_{\rm max}(H))^2}}
$$
Proving this amounts to showing that **(1.)** this $k'$ satisfies your inequality, that is,
$$
\frac{4\lambda_{\rm min}(H)\lambda_{\rm max}(H)}{(\lambda_{\rm min}(H)+\lambda_{\rm max}(H))^2}\operatorname{tr} (H^2 C) \le (\operatorname{tr} (H C))^2\tag{1}
$$
for all $C$ positive semi-definite of unit trace, and **(2.)** no larger $k'$ satisfies the inequality in question for *all* $C$.

1. Because $H$ is positive semi-definite we can spectrally decompose it as $\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_j(H)|g_j\rangle\langle g_j|$ where $(\lambda_{\rm min}(H)=)\lambda_1(H)\leq\ldots\leq\lambda_n(H)(=\lambda_{\rm max}(H))$ and $(g_j)_{j=1}^n$ is an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb C^n$.
   With this---because $H\neq 0$ so $\lambda_{\rm max}(H)>0$---Eq. (1) is equivalent to
   $$
   4\lambda_{\rm min}(H)\lambda_{\rm max}(H)\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_j^2\langle g_j,C g_j\rangle \le (\lambda_{\rm min}(H)+\lambda_{\rm max}(H))^2\Big(\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_j\langle g_j,C g_j\rangle\Big)^2\,.
   $$
   Note that only the diagonal elements of $C$ (in some basis) enter this inequality, meaning we can replace it by a probability vector (of diagonal elements) $r\in\mathbb R^n$: $C\geq 0$ implies $r\geq 0$ and $\operatorname{tr}(C)=1$ implies $\sum_{j=1}^nr_j=1$.
   With this we arrive at the following equivalent statement:

> **Lemma.** Let $n\in\mathbb N$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb R_+^n$ be given. If $\lambda_1\leq\ldots\leq\lambda_n$, then the map
> \begin{align*}
> f:\Delta^{n-1}&\to\mathbb R\\
> r&\mapsto (\lambda_1+\lambda_n)^2\langle\lambda,r\rangle^2-4\lambda_1\lambda_n\langle\lambda^2,r\rangle
> \end{align*}
> only takes non-negative values. Here, $\lambda^2:=(\lambda_j^2)_{j=1}^n$, and $\Delta^{n-1}$ is the standard simplex, that is, the set of all probability vectors in $\mathbb R^n$.

While I'm positive there exists an elementary proof for this, I only managed to show this using basic calculus:

> *Proof.* Obviously, $f$ is non-negative iff the minimal value $f$ takes is non-negative. With this slight re-formulation the central idea is that a differentiable function on a compact domain takes its minimum [either on the boundary or at a critical point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_theorem_(stationary_points)#Corollary).
> However, every $r\in\Delta^{n-1}$ is a boundary point (w.r.t. $\mathbb R^n$) because the trace hyperplane $\{r\in\mathbb R^n:r_1+\ldots+r_n=1\}$ has dimension one less than $\mathbb R^n$.
> Therefore we have to slightly tweak $f$:
> \begin{align*}
> \tilde f:\Delta^{n-2}_0&\to\mathbb R\\
> r&\mapsto f\begin{pmatrix}r\\1-r_1-\ldots-r_n\end{pmatrix}
> \end{align*}
> Here, $\Delta^{n-2}_0:=\operatorname{conv}\{\Delta^{n-2}\cup\{0\}\}=\{r\in\mathbb R^{n-1}_+:r_1+\ldots+r_n\leq1\}$ is a $n-1$-dimensional subset of $\mathbb R^{n-1}$. By definition, $\min_{x\in\Delta^{n-2}_0}\tilde f(x)=\min_{x\in\Delta^{n-1}}f(x)$ and this minimum exists because we are dealing with a [continuous function on a compact domain](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/109552). Thus if we can show $\min_{x\in\Delta^{n-2}_0}\tilde f(x)\geq 0$ for all $n\in\mathbb N\setminus\{1\}$ and all $\lambda\in\mathbb R_+^n$ then we are done. We do so via induction over $n$.
>
> - $n=2$: Let $x\in\Delta^{0}_0=[0,1]$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb R_+^2$. Then by direct computation
>   $$\tilde f(x)=f\begin{pmatrix}x\\1-x\end{pmatrix}=(\lambda_2-\lambda_1)^2\big(\lambda_1x-\lambda_2(1-x)\big)^2\geq 0
>   $$
> - $n\to n+1$: We will distinguish three cases. (1.) $\lambda_1=0$. Then $f(r)=\lambda_n^2\langle\lambda,r\rangle^2\geq 0$.
>   (2.) $\lambda$ has at most two distinct entries, that is, there exist $0\leq \alpha\leq\beta$ such that $\lambda=(\alpha,\ldots,\alpha,\beta,\ldots,\beta)^\top$. Then for all $r\in\Delta^{n-1}$ there exists $\xi\in[0,1]$ such that $f(r)=(\alpha-\beta)^2(r\alpha-(1-r)\beta)^2\geq 0$.
>   (3.) $\lambda_1>0$ and $\lambda$ has at least three distinct entries, that is, there exists $k\in\{2,\ldots,n\}$ such that $0<\lambda_1<\lambda_k<\lambda_{n+1}$. Because $\tilde f$ is differentiable and has compact domain, by the above argument we know that $\tilde f$ takes its minimum either on the boundary or at a critical point.
>   For the boundary observe that if some entries of $r$ are zero, then $f(r)=:f_{n+1}(\lambda,r)$ equals $f_m(\lambda',r')$ for some $m<n+1$ by definition; but $f_m$ is non-negative by induction hypothesis.
>   Thus all that is left is to compute the critical points of $f$; **we claim that assumption (3.) implies that $f$ has no critical points!**
>   Defining ${\bf e}:=(1,\ldots,1)^\top\in\mathbb R^n$ we for any $j=1,\ldots,n$ compute
>   \begin{align*}
>   \frac{\partial \tilde f}{\partial r_j}(r)&=\frac{\partial}{\partial r_j}\Big( (\lambda_1+\lambda_{n+1})^2\Big(\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_jr_j+\lambda_{n+1}(1-\langle {\bf e},r\rangle\Big)^2\\
>   &\qquad\qquad\qquad-4\lambda_1\lambda_{n+1} \Big(\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_j^2r_j+\lambda_{n+1}^2(1-\langle {\bf e},r\rangle\Big)\Big)\\
>   &=2(\lambda_1+\lambda_{n+1})^2\Big(\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_jr_j+\lambda_{n+1}(1-\langle {\bf e},r\rangle\Big)(\lambda_j-\lambda_{n+1})\\
>   &\qquad\qquad\qquad-4\lambda_1\lambda_{n+1} (\lambda_j^2-\lambda_{n+1}^2)\\
>   &=2(\lambda_{n+1}-\lambda_j)\Big(- (\lambda_1+\lambda_{n+1})^2\Big(\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_jr_j+\lambda_{n+1}(1-\langle {\bf e},r\rangle\Big)\\
>   &\qquad\qquad\qquad+2\lambda_1\lambda_{n+1} (\lambda_j+\lambda_{n+1}) \Big)\,.
>   \end{align*}
>   Now if $r^*$ is a critical point of $\tilde f$, then in particular $
>   \frac{\partial f}{\partial r_1}(r^*)=0=\frac{\partial f}{\partial r_k}(r^*) $. Because $\lambda_{n+1}>\lambda_k>\lambda_1>0$, this is equivalent to
>   $$
>   \lambda_1+\lambda_{n+1} =\frac{(\lambda_1+\lambda_{n+1})^2}{2\lambda_1\lambda_{n+1}}\Big(\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_jr_j^*+\lambda_{n+1}(1-\langle {\bf e},r^*\rangle\Big)
>   $$
>   and $$
>   \lambda_k+\lambda_{n+1} =\frac{(\lambda_1+\lambda_{n+1})^2}{2\lambda_1\lambda_{n+1} }\Big(\sum_{j=1}^n\lambda_jr_j^*+\lambda_{n+1}(1-\langle {\bf e},r^*\rangle\Big)\,.
>   $$
>   Observe that the r.h.s. is the same both times, but the left-hand sides do **not** coincide because $\lambda_1<\lambda_k$ by assumption. Therefore $\tilde f$ has no critical points meaning the minimum is taken on the boundary (recall that this is taken care of by the induction hypothesis). This concludes the proof. $\square$

2. It suffices to write down an explicit $C$ for which equality holds in (1). If $g_{\rm min}$ ($g_{\rm max}$) is any normalized eigenvector of $H$ w.r.t. the eigenvalue $\lambda_{\rm min}(H)$ ($\lambda_{\rm max}(H)$), then such $C$ is for example given by the following rank-2 state:
   $$
   \boxed{\frac{\lambda_{\rm max}(H)}{\lambda_{\rm min}(H)+\lambda_{\rm max}(H)}|g_{\rm min}\rangle\langle g_{\rm min}|+\frac{\lambda_{\rm min}(H)}{\lambda_{\rm min}(H)+\lambda_{\rm max}(H)}|g_{\rm max}\rangle\langle g_{\rm max}|}
   $$
   Pluigging this $C$ into (1) yields equality so the $k'$ we specified cannot be chosen any lower; this concludes the proof.

Two little remarks:

- It is easy to see that this $k'$ is better than the bound from your previous question:
  \begin{align*}
  \frac{4\lambda_{\rm min}(H)\lambda_{\rm max}(H)}{(\lambda_{\rm min}(H)+\lambda_{\rm max}(H))^2}&\geq \frac{4\lambda_{\rm min}^2(H)}{(\lambda_{\rm min}(H)+\lambda_{\rm max}(H))^2}\\
  &\geq \frac{4\lambda_{\rm min}^2(H)}{(\lambda_{\rm max}(H)+\lambda_{\rm max}(H))^2}=\frac{\lambda_{\rm min}(H)^2}{\lambda_{\rm max}(H)^2}\,,
  \end{align*}
  and equality holds if and only if $\lambda_{\rm min}(H)=0$ or $H$ is a multiple of the identity.
- Some slight algebraic manipulation shows that if $H>0$, then $k'$ is the ratio of the harmonic mean to the arithmetic mean of the smallest and the largest eigenvalue of $H$:
  $$
  k'=\frac{ \Big(\frac{ 2 }{ \frac{1}{\lambda_{\rm min}(H)}+\frac{1}{\lambda_{\rm max}(H)} } \Big)}{ \Big(\frac{\lambda_{\rm min}(H)+\lambda_{\rm max}(H)  }{ 2 }\Big) }
  $$
  As a direct consequence of the [HM-AM-inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HM-GM-AM-QM_inequalities) we find $k'\leq 1$, meaning for $H\geq 0$ and all $\tilde k>1$ there exists $C\geq 0$ of unit trace such that $\tilde k\operatorname{tr}(H^2C)\not\leq(\operatorname{tr}(HC))^2$. Indeed if $\psi_j\in\mathbb C^n$ is some normalized eigenvector to a non-zero eigenvalue $\lambda_j$ of $H$, then $C:=|\psi_j\rangle\langle\psi_j|$ does the job: $\tilde k\operatorname{tr}(H^2C)=\tilde k \lambda_j^2 >\lambda_j^2=(\operatorname{tr}(HC))^2$.

Comment: Nice! I figured this would be piece of cake for someone from Quantum Information :)

Comment: BTW, in version 13 the code is much simpler: `h = {1, 1, 1, 10};
Minimize[(h . c)^2/((h*h) . c), 
 c \[Element] Simplex@IdentityMatrix@Length[h]]`

Answer (score 3):

As shown in the other answer, the result is closely related to Kantorovich-typed inequalities.

Assume for the moment that $H$ is positive definite. Let $M$ and $m$ be its largest and smallest eigenvalues respectively. Then $MI-H$ and $H-mI$ are two commuting positive semidefinite matrices. Hence $0\le(MI-H)(H-mI)$, i.e., $H^2\le(M+m)H-MmI$. It follows that $C^{1/2}H^2C^{1/2}\le(M+m)C^{1/2}HC^{1/2}-MmC$ and in turn,
$\operatorname{tr}H^2C\le(M+m)\operatorname{tr}HC-Mm$. So, by completing square for the RHS, we obtain
$$
\operatorname{tr}H^2C
\le(M+m)\operatorname{tr}HC-Mm
\le\frac{(M+m)^2}{4Mm}(\operatorname{tr}HC)^2.
$$
Therefore
$$
4Mm\operatorname{tr}H^2C
\le(M+m)^2(\operatorname{tr}HC)^2
$$
and this inequality still holds when $H$ is positive semidefinite, by a continuity argument. It is also sharp. Equality occurs, for instance, when $H$ is a scalar matrix.